# What should I use to create multiple variables inside functions with user inputting how many variables there are?

Tags: pandas, list, variables

I am having pandas read a csv, the user inputs how ever many airports they want to and the csv records those. Then I have the csv imported into a separate script, which needs to run commands based off how many variables the user selected. I just currently wrote out 22 different if... elif... else statements and manually put the variables in, there has to be a more efficient easier way.

following is an example, I wrote in ans1-ans22 with the same thing. I instead want the ans# to be based off how many inputs the user creates, and some variables to follow

```
 ans1 = metar.loc[ap1, 'flight_category']
 ans2 = metar.loc[ap2, 'flight_category']
```

then later on...

```
    if ans1 == 'VFR':
        led1 = 'GREEN'
        pixels[0] = grn
    elif ans1 == 'MVFR':
        led1 = 'BLUE'
        pixels[0] = blu
    elif ans1 == 'IFR':
        led1 = 'RED'
        pixels[0] = red
    elif ans1 == 'LIFR':
        led1 = 'PINK'
        pixels[0] = pnk
    else:
        print('ERROR')

    if ans2 == 'VFR':
        led2 = 'GREEN'
        pixels[2] = grn
    elif ans2 == 'MVFR':
        led2 = 'BLUE'
        pixels[2] = blu
    elif ans2 == 'IFR':
        led2 = 'RED'
        pixels[2] = red
    elif ans2 == 'LIFR':
        led2 = 'PINK'
        pixels[2] = pnk
    else:
        print('ERROR')
```

if there is an easier way to do this it would help me out so much, I am new here and just learning on youtube right now! Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want specific things to be executed based on the value of "ans" variables, but without all the if statements.

That can be done by using lists.

```
possibleAns = ['VFR', 'MVFR', 'IFR', 'LIFR']
possibleLed = ['GREEN', 'BLUE', 'RED', 'PINK']
possiblePixels = [grn, blu, red, pnk]

if(ans1 in possibleAns1):
    index = possibleAns.index(ans1);
    led1 = possibleLed[index]
    pixels[0] = possiblePixels[index]
else:
    print('ERROR')

# Do the same for ans2
```

As for the multiple function inputs, you might want to check out "argv" and "kwargs".